# Socket io not working during deployment on vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, websocket, socket.io, vercel

I cannot use socket io during deployment on vercel.
How to add socket.io in vercel during production? If not what can be other alternatives for real-time communication.
I used nextJS frontend, nodejs for backend and socket for real time communication.

I searched web for answers.